# About the Linear Quotients of Square of an Ideal with Linear Quotients

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $I$ be a monomial ideal generated by quadratic monomials $u_{1},...,u_{s}$ and suppose that $I$ has linear quotients with respect to this given ordering. Is it true or false that $I^{2}$ has linear quotients with respect to the lexicographic ordering
$u_{1}^{2},u_{1}u_{2},...,u_{1}u_{s},u_{2}^{2},u_{2}u_{3},...,u_{s}^{2}$?

I have tried many examples and got the answer in positive. Would someone please help me to prove or give some counterexample?

When I try to prove that $I^{2}$ has linear quotients with respect to the given ordering, I can prove upto $(u_{1}^{2},u_{1}u_{2},...,u_{1}u_{s}):u_{2}^{2}$ that this and all the previous qoutient ideals are generated by linear forms by using the fact that $I$ has linear quotients with respect to the ordering $u_{1},...,u_{s}$. On the next step I am stuck how to prove that $(u_{1}^{2},u_{1}u_{2},...,u_{1}u_{s},u_{2}^{2}):u_{2}u_{3}$ is generated by linear forms.

On the other hand, there are well-known counterexamples of two ideals(generated by cubic monomials) and one ideal(generated by quadratic monomials and one quadratic binomial) which have linear quotients but their squares do not have. But I could not find any counterexample of ideal generated by quadratic monomials.

Comment: What do you mean by "linear quotient"?

Comment: @YACP $I$ has linear quotients with respect to the ordering of the generators $u_{1},...,u_{s}$. This means that $(u_{1},...,u_{i-1}):u_{i}$ is generated by linear forms for all $i\geq 2$.